# Iterate through array and change background color of each UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicolor

I am trying to better understand UITableViews and building them from scratch. I want to build a table view that displays a different background color for each cell. I have built out a ColorModel class that holds an array of type UIColors. All of my tableview cells are displaying a red background which is the last color in the array. Here is that snippet:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ColorModel {

static var colors = [
    UIColor.white,
    UIColor.blue,
    UIColor.black,
    UIColor.brown,
    UIColor.cyan,
    UIColor.green,
    UIColor.red
]

}
```

Here is my main view controller syntax:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var colorList = ColorModel.colors

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return colorList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ColorCell", for: indexPath)
    for color in colorList {
        cell.backgroundColor = color
    }
    return cell
}


}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `static var colors: [UIColor] = [.white, .blue, .black, .brown, .cyan, .green, .red]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `indexPath.row` to get the color for every cell from the array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ColorCell", for: indexPath)

     let color = colorList[indexPath.row]
     cell.backgroundColor = color

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was stuck thinking I needed to use a for loop.

Comment: To the OP: The `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` function is passed a single `indexPath` at a time, and returns a single cell at a time. The table view calls it over and over, asking for a different cell each time. You wait for the table view to call it for each cell that needs to be displayed. You never loop through all the cells in that method.